# Problem with symfony2 schema yaml: unable to get relationships working

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I have two entities: User and Student. Following is the yaml schema:

```
ABC\UserBundle\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  table: abc_user
  id:
    id:       { type: integer, generator: { strategy: AUTO } }
  fields:        
    username: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true, unique: true }
    email:    { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true, unique: true }
    password: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
    enabled:  { type: boolean }


ABC\UserBundle\Entity\Student:
  type: entity
  table: abc_student
  id:
    id: { type: integer, generator: { strategy: AUTO } }        
  fields:
    first_name: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
    middle_name: { type: string, length: 255 }
    last_name: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
  OnetoOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: ABC\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

My problem is that when I do "doctine:update:schema --dump-sql", user_id field is not added to the Student table and no relationship is created between the entities.

Answer (score 1):

Yaml map is case-sensitive, use the proper name `oneToOne` for creating relations.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps, I picked up 'OneToOne' from annotation examples on doctrine documentation page. I'll try with 'oneToOne' and see if it helps.

Comment: Changing 'OneToOne' to 'oneToOne' didn't do any help. I also tried validating schema using the Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaValidator class but it returns no error.

Comment: I converted my schema from yaml to xml using doctrine:mapping:convert command, added the one-to-one mapping in xml and it worked.

Though, still not sure if the original problem was due to my mistake, or it is a bug in symfony/doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing the joinColumn option for the OneToOne association:

```
ABC\UserBundle\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  table: abc_user
  id:
    id:       { type: integer, generator: { strategy: AUTO } }
  fields:        
    username: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true, unique: true }
    email:    { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true, unique: true }
    password: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
    enabled:  { type: boolean }
  OnetoOne:
    student:
      targetEntity: ABC\UserBundle\Entity\Student
      mappedBy: user

ABC\UserBundle\Entity\Student:
  type: entity
  table: abc_student
  id:
    id: { type: integer, generator: { strategy: AUTO } }        
  fields:
    first_name: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
    middle_name: { type: string, length: 255 }
    last_name: { type: string, length: 255, notnull: true }
  OnetoOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: ABC\UserBundle\Entity\User
      joinColumn:
        name: user_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted a one-to-one unidirectional mapping, that's why I put the relation only in Student entity. Also, it should pick up name = 'user_id' and referencedColumnName = 'id' by default. I tried this too earlier, but it didn't help. I'll give it a go once again today evening and see if I can get anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, joinColumn is optional, so disregard my answer. The real problem here is the capitalization of **OnetoOne** that should be **oneToOne** as stated in another answer.